# Deep Clone gem for rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found this http://rubygems.org/gems/deep_cloneable
but it has only been tested with rails 3.

I tried it out, but all of my active record models became undefined. lol.
specifically: `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)`

So, I was wondering if there is any sort of active record deep clone gem for rails 2?

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not very kind, but: RTFM

```
Installation

Install by adding the gem to your Gemfile

gem ‘deep_cloneable’

Rails 2:

gem install deep_cloneable, ‘~> 1.2.4’
```

Comment: my error still stands. -> removing the gem removes the error. so, I came to the conclusion the gem was not compatible with rails 2.

Comment: error persists.  I'm using bundler, btw. Though that shouldn't matter.... unless there is some external lib it uses.

Comment: yeaah, and WHAT VERSION are you using?